# OpenERP7.0 ref could not use in domain, how could I get group_id

Tags: python, odoo

I try to get group id like this

```
<field name="domain">[('state','=','wait_prove'),('shenqr.user_id.groups_id', '=', ref('group_staff'))]</field>
```

the result is:  name 'ref' is not defined

how can I get group id , thanks!

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_qingjia_qingjdprove_new_fjl">
    <field name="name">wait_proved</field>
     <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">qingjia.qingjd</field>
    <field name="domain">[('state','=','wait_prove'),('tians', '&lt;=', 1),('shenqr.user_id','&lt;&gt;',uid),('shenqr.user_id.groups_id', '=', ref('group_staff'))]</field>
      <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_qingjd_tree"/>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="context">{}</field>
</record>
```

Comment: Do you already have created record named 'group_staff' in demo or data xml file ?

Comment: where are you adding this domain. can you show the complete record where this domain is specified

Comment: thanks ,I have already created record named group_staff